# Inconsistent '%f' behaviour between boost::posix_time::time_facet and boost::posix_time::time_input_facet

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to convert a `boost::posix_time::ptime` to a specific string format (extended ISO) and then back to a `boost::posix_time::ptime`.

Surprisingly, it looks like for `boost::posix_time::time_facet` `%f` means `000000` to `999999` (with no decimal separator). But for `boost::posix_time::time_input_facet`, it means `.000000` to `.999999` (with decimal separator).

See:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    auto now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();

    std::stringstream outStr;
    {
        boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet();
        facet->format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f");
        outStr.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), facet));
        outStr << now;
    }
    std::cout << outStr.str() << std::endl;

    {
        static const std::string format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f";
        const std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet(format));
        std::istringstream is(outStr.str());
        is.imbue(loc);
        boost::posix_time::ptime converted;
        is >> converted;
        std::cout << converted << std::endl;
    }

    {
        static const std::string format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%f";
        const std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet(format));
        std::istringstream is(outStr.str());
        is.imbue(loc);
        boost::posix_time::ptime converted;
        is >> converted;
        std::cout << converted << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[This outputs](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DUviOWBADZ8A4FYG):

```
2019-04-30T12:23:29.000000
not-a-date-time
2019-Apr-30 12:23:29
```

While I would expect:

```
2019-04-30T12:23:29.000000
2019-Apr-30 12:23:29
not-a-date-time
```

I'm using boost 1.68.

Am I doing something wrong or is that a bug in `boost::posix_time::time_facet` or `boost::posix_time::input_time_facet`?

Note: '%F' does not have this problem.

Comment: Your [example tweaked](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EpEhGn7HcGu9nvre) (more readable) comparing to [different seconds separator](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SW761Gohszdj3VA4) which doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely a boost bug. I fill the issue here:
https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/issues/102

Using `%F` works better but has different behaviour if time has no decimal information:
[Try this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mgJdVUzxsm2UywtY)